# How to retrieve D365 Area name using JavaScript

Tags: dynamics-365

It's all in the title. I'm looking for a way to programmatically retrieve the active area name to do some test
I looked in the ui and navigation items, but there seem to be no way to achieving this.
Looked into the MS Documentation as well but in vain.
If someone could please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve with this? what is your end goal?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is the thing : I am using the same Entity in two different work Areas, so my end goal is to, according to the area that the end user had chosen, show a different form (and ultimately set a different view as default every time the Work Areas are switched)

Comment: @nzr_sdd, if your area is one of the sitemap areas, then you may edit the sitemap, change the entity to some certain URL, and you can specify your view id or form id.